# Need to parse this dumpsys output (preferably with Perl)

Tags: perl, awk, sed, grep

I have a problem. I need to parse this dumpsys output given below:

```
 Activity Resolver Table:
 Non-Data Actions:
    android.intent.action.MAIN:
    422df0c8.   com.sec.factory.camera/com.sec.android.app.camerafirmware.CameraFirmware filter 422df360
       Action: "android.intent.action.MAIN"
      Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
    422df610 com.sec.factory.camera/com.sec.android.app.camerafirmware.CameraFirmware_user filter 422b65f0
      Action: "android.intent.action.MAIN"
      Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
    420d08e8 com.sec.factory.camera/com.sec.android.app.camerafirmware.CameraFirmwareUpdate_Booting filter 420d0ac8
      Action: "android.intent.action.MAIN"
      Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
  com.sec.android.app.camaftest.SCAN:
    420a2220 com.sec.factory.camera/com.sec.android.app.camaftest.CaptureActivity filter 4209f468
      Action: "com.sec.android.app.camaftest.SCAN"
      Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"

Receiver Resolver Table:
 Schemes:
    android_secret_code:
     422b69b0.   com.sec.factory.camera/com.sec.android.app.camerafirmware.CameraFirmwareBroadCastReceiver filter 422b6b80
       Action:   "android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE"
       Scheme:  "android_secret_code"
      Authority: "34971539": -1
      Authority: "7412365": -1

Non-Data Actions:
    android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED:
     420d0c70. com.sec.factory.camera/com.sec.android.app.camerafirmware.CameraFirmwareBroadCastReceiver filter 420d0d18
       Action: "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"
```

From this output (from a tool called dumpsys in android), I would like to get the content under the `Non-Data Actions:` heading *only* (I do not, for example, want content under the `Receiver Resolver Table:` heading).

I want to do this preferably in Perl, but other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say if you want the heading itself - here I've presumed you do want it.  This is written "Unix filter" style, meaning you need to pipe the dump data into it or supply the filename that contains the data as the first parameter to the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.12;

my $target = 'Non-Data \s+ Actions:';
my $taking_data = 0;

while (<>) {
   $taking_data = 1 if (/ ^ \s* $target \s* /x) ;
   print if $taking_data;
   $taking_data = 0 if / ^ \s* $ /x ;
}
```

Ran like so: `$ cat dump_data.txt | ./android.pl` or `$ ./android.pl dump_data.txt` produces:

```
Non-Data Actions:
    android.intent.action.MAIN:
    422df0c8.   com.sec.factory.camera/com.sec.android.app.camerafirmware.CameraFirmware filter 422df360
       Action: "android.intent.action.MAIN"
      Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
    422df610 com.sec.factory.camera/com.sec.android.app.camerafirmware.CameraFirmware_user filter 422b65f0
      Action: "android.intent.action.MAIN"
      Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
    420d08e8 com.sec.factory.camera/com.sec.android.app.camerafirmware.CameraFirmwareUpdate_Booting filter 420d0ac8
      Action: "android.intent.action.MAIN"
      Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
  com.sec.android.app.camaftest.SCAN:
    420a2220 com.sec.factory.camera/com.sec.android.app.camaftest.CaptureActivity filter 4209f468
      Action: "com.sec.android.app.camaftest.SCAN"
      Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"

Non-Data Actions:
    android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED:
     420d0c70. com.sec.factory.camera/com.sec.android.app.camerafirmware.CameraFirmwareBroadCastReceiver filter 420d0d18
       Action: "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"
```

There's not much to it; set a flag if we find the target on a line by itself optionally surrounded by whitespace; clear the flag if we see a blank line; and in between; print the line if the flag is set.

The **'/x'** on the end of the regex switches on **"extended mode"** which allows ***insignificant*** whitespace in the regex to make for a clearer layout.

Comment: Yes,exactly what i needed.Thanks!

Comment: If it's exactly what you want, please consider up-votting and/or accepting the answer.

Comment: Oops I forgot lol...Perfect answer though.I'm new to Perl,so need a little help over here.Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how exactly these logs are formatted, you can select the blocks you want with sed, assuming for example that every block is followed by an empty line:

```
$ sed -n '/Non-Data Actions:/,/^$/p' dumpsys
 Non-Data Actions:
    android.intent.action.MAIN:
    422df0c8.   com.sec.factory.camera/com.sec.android.app.camerafirmware.CameraFirmware filter 422df360
       Action: "android.intent.action.MAIN"
      Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
    422df610 com.sec.factory.camera/com.sec.android.app.camerafirmware.CameraFirmware_user filter 422b65f0
      Action: "android.intent.action.MAIN"
      Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
    420d08e8 com.sec.factory.camera/com.sec.android.app.camerafirmware.CameraFirmwareUpdate_Booting filter 420d0ac8
      Action: "android.intent.action.MAIN"
      Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
  com.sec.android.app.camaftest.SCAN:
    420a2220 com.sec.factory.camera/com.sec.android.app.camaftest.CaptureActivity filter 4209f468
      Action: "com.sec.android.app.camaftest.SCAN"
      Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"

Non-Data Actions:
    android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED:
     420d0c70. com.sec.factory.camera/com.sec.android.app.camerafirmware.CameraFirmwareBroadCastReceiver filter 420d0d18
       Action: "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"
```